# How to sort datetime in datagridview?

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I have this code of sorting in descending but it give's me sorting of one digit of date first then go for two digits of date

`this.gv_Attlog.Sort(this.gv_Attlog.Columns[1],ListSortDirection.Descending);`

Sample output

```
2019-09-9 12:12:12
2019-09-8 12:12:12
2019-09-7 12:12:12
2019-09-6 12:12:12
2019-09-5 12:12:12
2019-09-4 12:12:12
2019-09-3 12:12:12
2019-09-2 12:12:12
2019-09-1 12:12:12
2019-09-31 12:12:12
2019-09-30 12:12:12
2019-09-29 12:12:12
2019-09-27 12:12:12
2019-09-26 12:12:12
2019-09-25 12:12:12
2019-09-24 12:12:12
2019-09-23 12:12:12
2019-09-22 12:12:12
2019-09-21 12:12:12 ........
```

What i want output is :

```
2019-09-31 12:12:12
2019-09-30 12:12:12
2019-09-29 12:12:12
2019-09-27 12:12:12
2019-09-26 12:12:12
2019-09-25 12:12:12
2019-09-24 12:12:12
2019-09-23 12:12:12
2019-09-22 12:12:12
2019-09-21 12:12:12 
....
2019-09-9 12:12:12
2019-09-8 12:12:12
2019-09-7 12:12:12
2019-09-6 12:12:12
2019-09-5 12:12:12
2019-09-4 12:12:12
2019-09-3 12:12:12
2019-09-2 12:12:12
2019-09-1 12:12:12
```

Comment: Are you filling the DGV with dates or strings

Comment: @Flydog57 It's String `dt_period.Columns.Add("Verify Date", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));`

Comment: Then it's going to sort as a string.  Add in DateTimes (i.e., not strings), and use the formatting mechanism to display how it shows up to the user.  For what it's worth, you may want to use `typeof(string)` rather than `System.Type.GetType("System.String")` - it's easier to read, easier to type and ever so slightly faster

Comment: @Flydog57 does it possible to make a date and time format in `typeof(datetime)` ? how if it is..

Comment: If you have a cell (or column) in a cell you want to format in a specific way, you do that using the CellFormatting event. The C# docs for that event include formatting a column as a short date. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting